# How i can execute function?

Tags: sql, oracle, pdo

SQL code work in Oracle SQL Developer, but not work in PHP PDO
example:

```
    $sql = <<<SQL
      var sss varchar2(1000);
      begin
        :sss := AFACE_WWW_PNAL_SAVE(
          54687,
          10.66,
          'Description'
        );
      end;
SQL;
    $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $pdo->query($sql); -- Exception
```

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 900 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

How i can get result in "sss" variable?

Comment: `var[iable]` is a SQL Developer (and SQL\*Plus/SQLcl) client-specific declaration of a bind variable. It is not part of the SQL, or even PL/SQL, language.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if PL/SQL blocks are even allowed there, but if they are you may miss a `DECLARE` at the beginning.

But you don't need PL/SQL to get a value from a function. You can query `dual`.

```
SELECT aface_www_pnal_save(54687, 10.66, 'Description') sss
       FROM dual;
```

Comment: Then i can next Exception:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 14552 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML`

Comment: @John: Please edit your question and include the definition of the function.

Comment: @John: Having DML or DML or `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` in a function is not good at all. I strongly suggest, that you don't do that. Besides that, try the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` as suggested in the Oracle forum.